# can well ordered principle express in predicate logic or propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I came to a question like the title, which I reckon should be able to express in propositional logic. **I am still confused what kind of statements are able to express in propostional logic or predicate logic.**

> Every nonempty subset of positive integers has a least element.

Here is my interpretation:

Let $X$ be non empty subset.$N(X)$be nonempty subset of natural numbers.$\:L(X)$means exists least element in X.

$$\forall X(N(X)\wedge L(X))\:\text{Here not very sure $\wedge$ or $\implies$}$$

The Negation will be

$$\exists (\neg N(X)\lor\neg L(X)) $$

I am not sure if it's correct, any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: For "For all" it is $\Longrightarrow$, "There exists" is $\wedge$.

Comment: See [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2019/entries/logic-higher-order/#1) for an example of formalization in High-Order Predicate Logic.

Comment: Propositional logic is not expressive enough; we need predicate logic.

Comment: It also can't be expressed as a first-order logical statement in the language of strict orders.  (Took me a while to come up with an argument why not: in any ultraproduct of $\mathbb{N}$, let $x_0:=(0,1,2,3,\ldots)$, $x_1:=(0,0,1,2,\ldots)$, etc.  Then in the ultraproduct, $\cdots < x_2 < x_1 < x_0$.  So, we've found an ultraproduct of well-orders which is not a well-order.)  But you *can* write a "strong induction" axiom schema which should allow you to do a lot of what you would do with a well-order anyway.

Comment: I guess there's also a compactness argument (which eluded me before): if you extend the language with $\omega$ constant symbols $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$, then the negation of a "well-ordered" statement would be a consequence of axioms $\phi_n := (x_{n+1} < x_n)$.  So by compactness, it would be a consequence of some finite subset $\phi_0, \ldots, \phi_m$.  But this finite subset is satisfied by the model $(\mathbb{N}, <, m+1, m, \ldots, 1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$, giving a contradiction.  So, if we can't even write a first-order statement in the extended language for the domain being well-ordered...